# Ajax call giving 404 in Lumen 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, routes, lumen

I have a super simple test env that makes an ajax call to one of my controllers in Lumen 5.3, but I'm getting a 404. From what I gather from the docs, this should work:

#### routes.php

```
 $app->post('login', 'LoginController@index');
```

#### LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LoginController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return response()->json(['success' => true], 200);
    }

}
```

#### index.blade.php

```
$('#sign-in').on('click', function () {
    $.post('login', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).done(function () {
        console.log('Ajax call complete');
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log(error.status); // gives 404
    });
});
```

Comment: This `$.post('login')` should be an absolute path.

Comment: Absolute path or otherwise, it still posts to the correct Url

Comment: @djthoms please check your routes registerd or not.

Comment: @AjayPatel what do you mean?

Comment: @djthoms By default lumen does not provide you list of routes like laravel one. you can get list of routes in your lumen application using this package. https://github.com/appzcoder/lumen-route-list

Comment: @djthoms add it. i am pretty sure it will help you a lot.